# I cannot upload any file from GitBash after uploading then deleting a big file in GitHub

Tags: github, git-bash

Accidentally uploaded a big file to GitHub, then deleted it in local repository. After this action, everytime I want to upload file, it tells me there is a big file. However, when I try to find it on my repository, GitHub cannot find it. Now I cannot upload any file from GitBash. Is the big file hide somewhere I didn't notice? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you, you do not have changes in local

Do a `git reset --hard origin/<remote branch name>`

to update your local workspace with remote , try adding new files and commit it , check if you get the same error.

By this you will get that big file / same remote code to your local , check for big file > 100 MB and take action